# Распарсить значение в MySql

Tags: php, sql

Всем привет. Есть таблица новости, есть столбец text
Значение такое

```
<h2 class="inset" _mce_style="text-align: center;" style="text-align: center;"><strong>По информации DW, дрезденская НПО передала  Антикоррупционному агентству Казахстана документы о счетах чиновников, на  которых за пределами республики лежат «грязные деньги». Что дальше?</strong></h2>
<p align="left"><img src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg" _mce_src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg" class="caption" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" _mce_style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"><br></p><p align="left"><strong><em>Восьмого декабря, за  трое суток до перевода на пост генерального прокурора республики, тогда еще  председатель казахстанского Агентства по делам государственной службы и  противодействию коррупции Кайрат Кожамжаров объявил о наличии черного списка,  включающего имена бывших чиновников, которые прячут в офшорах миллиарды  долларов. По словам Кожамжарова, в списке 53 человека, часть из них скрывается  за границей, а сумма выведенных ими из Казахстана средств оценивается в более  чем 8 миллиардов долларов.</em></strong></p>
<p align="center"><strong></strong></p>
```

Можно как то отсюда получить полностью весь тег img и записать в другой столбец?

Comment: Найти `<img`, найти первое `>` после него, выкусить всё, что между ними.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить значение тега  можно так:

```
$str = '<h2 class="inset" _mce_style="text-align: center;" style="text-align: center;"><strong>По информации DW, дрезденская НПО передала  Антикоррупционному агентству Казахстана документы о счетах чиновников, на  которых за пределами республики лежат «грязные деньги». Что дальше?</strong></h2>
<p align="left"><img src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg" _mce_src="images/stories/2017/12/2-51.jpg" class="caption" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" _mce_style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"><br></p><p align="left"><strong><em>Восьмого декабря, за  трое суток до перевода на пост генерального прокурора республики, тогда еще  председатель казахстанского Агентства по делам государственной службы и  противодействию коррупции Кайрат Кожамжаров объявил о наличии черного списка,  включающего имена бывших чиновников, которые прячут в офшорах миллиарды  долларов. По словам Кожамжарова, в списке 53 человека, часть из них скрывается  за границей, а сумма выведенных ими из Казахстана средств оценивается в более  чем 8 миллиардов долларов.</em></strong></p>
<p align="center"><strong></strong></p>';

$patt = '~<img[^>]*>~';
preg_match($patt, $str, $a);

var_dump($a[0]);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Только средствами php?

Comment: @duddeniska нет, этот пример скорее для "если средствами php".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT('<img', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`text`, '<img', -1), '>', 1), '>')
FROM `table`
```

Корректно работает лишь в случае, когда тег IMG единственный, и не содержит в теле тега символа `>` (например, в каком-нибудь строковом литерале).

Comment: а почему не regex'ом для mysql?

Comment: @Эдуард В MySQL реги могут только проверить на соответствие шаблону. не более.

Comment: вот как? Я даже не предполагал, на сколько они "слабы" в mysql... Спасибо за инфо.